# Caching the results of the function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I use the following function to generate GUID:

```
import Data.UUID as UV
import Data.UUID.V1 as UV1

generateUUID :: String
generateUUID = UV.toString $ fromJust $ unsafePerformIO UV1.nextUUID
```

And I use the `generateUUID` for the creation of elements

```
createWidgetUI element uuid =
    WidgetUI { wui_title    = ""
             , wui_id       = uuid
             , wui_attr_style = ""
             , wui_attr_class = ""
             , wui_styles   = []
             , wui_scripts  = []
             , wui_contents = []
             , wui_children = []
             , wui_element  = element
             }

wuiPanel :: UI WidgetUI
wuiPanel = do
    return $ createWidgetUI elem uuid
    where
        uuid = generateUUID
        elem = ContainerUI $ H.div
```

When I call the method `wuiPanel` several times, I get same UUID value! But I need to every call the method `wuiPanel` to get elements with different UUID value. I can not understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you rework the UUID generation so that it fits the `UI` monad you are working in. `unsafe` things are best to be avoided in general -- especially in cases like yours where you use those to *lie* to the compiler: a type like `String` promises the value is a fixed, constant string value, allowing the compiler to optimize assuming this. This will make the code very, very fragile, in that it might work or not depending on the optimizations.

In the code below, I am guessing a few types, so this could not match exactly with your library.

```
generateUUID :: IO String
generateUUID = UV.toString . fromJust <$> UV1.nextUUID

wuiPanel :: UI WidgetUI
wuiPanel = do
    uuid <- liftIO generateUUID
    let elem = ContainerUI $ H.div
    return $ createWidgetUI elem uuid
```

To do: better handling of `nextUUID`, which might return `Nothing` "if you request UUIDs too quickly" (scary quote from the docs). Are you sure you can't use the `V4.nextRandom` which will never return `Nothing`s?

Comment: It appears you are using the [UI monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#g:3) from the [threepenny package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.6) - right?

Comment: I have no idea what the OP is using -- you are probably right.

Comment: UI monad not from  threepenny package! Monad is written by me `data UI a = UI a`. And instance Functor, Applicativ, Monad for UI.

Comment: I'm just developing a wrapper for Blaze.

Comment: But How can I release `liftIO :: UI a -> IO a`?

Comment: I tryed to use `IO` instead `UI`. Everything is working!!! Thank you!!!But still I want to use my `UI` monad. If I release `liftIO :: UI a -> IO a`, then wil be OK? but HOW?

Comment: I will do so `type UI == IO`.But I do not like this solution.